# A more elegant way to write this .map call?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I have some code that essentially takes an array of objects and just adds an additional key to each item. I want to be able to express this as tersely as possible as an experiment.

```
let fruits = [
   {"type" : "orange"},
   {"type" : "apple"},
   {"type" : "banana"}
];
console.log(fruits.map((fruit) => {
         fruit.price = "$1.00";
         return fruit;
}));
```

Currently, this works, but it's certainly no one liner and the `return` statement is still in there, and I feel like there's a way to get rid of it given the fat arrow syntax.

Comment: As I painfully figured out after 4 hours of debugging a strange problem, the object given to the map function is the actual object from the original array. This means you may not actually have to have a return in the function in this case. The original array will be modified

Comment: _"just adds an additional key"_ - Which means there is no mapping involved. So `map` is not the right tool to begin with.

Comment: I don't know why Felix Kling removed the ES6 tag.... it's essentially asking about how to write code around fat arrows. @Suppen: thanks for pointing that out. In my case, I do want to return because I want to use method chaining with the results.

Comment: To put this simply: `map` is what to use when you are doing a transformation, and the size of the input is equivalent to the size of the output.  In this case, I am not modifying the size of `fruits` so `map` is the correct tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to extend the object and also return the resulting newly-created object:

```
console.log(fruits.map(fruit => Object.assign(fruit, { price: "1.00" })));
```

[Babel REPL Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20fruits%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%7B%22type%22%20%3A%20%22orange%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22type%22%20%3A%20%22apple%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%7B%22type%22%20%3A%20%22banana%22%7D%0A%5D%3B%0Aconsole.log(fruits.map(fruit%20%3D%3E%20Object.assign(fruit%2C%20%7B%20price%3A%20%221.00%22%20%7D))))

This removes the need for the `return` keyword, but it's hardly the biggest space-saver. It is also equivalent to what you already have (in that the original `fruit` object is modified. As joews points out below, if you wanted to leave the original array in-tact you can use an empty target object like so:

```
Object.assign({}, fruit, { price: "1.00"});
```

This will ensure that your original array is unmodified (which may or may not be what you want).

Finally, combining this with the spread operator gives us:

```
console.log(fruits.map(fruit => ({...fruit, price: "1.00" })));
```

Comment: This does actually change `fruit`. To create a new object you could `Object.assign({}, fruit, { price: "1.00"})`.

Comment: Object.assign is looking like the way to go. In my case, mutability /immutability is not a concern, so I think I'll end up going with your first example.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `.forEach()` instead of `.map()` to directly modify `fruits` if you don't need the original version of `fruits`

```
fruits.forEach((fruit) => fruit.price = "$1.00");
```

http://www.es6fiddle.net/igwdk0gk/

Comment: The forEach makes sense, but in the scope of the larger script, I would like to pass fruits back to another piece of code. forEach returns nothing unfortunately, so it doesn't support nice method chaining (which is why I wanted to use .map)

Comment: This info should have been part of the question

Comment: I sort of implied it with the functional-programming tag, but I guess that could've been more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Could do something like this, not recommended for readibility but technically one line.

```
fruits.map(fruit => (fruit.price = "$1.00") && fruit);
```

As others have mentioned this method just adds a property to the object and does not copy it. A simple way to keep this as a one liner, use a map and actually create a copy would be:

```
fruits.map(fruit => Object.assign({price: "$1.00"}, fruit));
```

`Object.assign()` will assign all the properties of `fruit` to the object `{ price: "$1.00" }` and return it.

Live example:

```js
"use strict";

let log = function() {
  output.textContent += [].join.call(arguments, ' ') + '\n\n';
};

log('# MAP (OR FOREACH) WITHOUT ASSIGN');

let fruits = [
   {"type" : "orange"},
   {"type" : "apple"},
   {"type" : "banana"}
];
let newfruits = fruits.map(fruit => (fruit.price = "$1.00") && fruit);

log('fruits', JSON.stringify(fruits));
log('newfruits', JSON.stringify(newfruits));
log('^-- Both are modified since newfruits its a new array with the same objects');

log('# MAP WITH ASSIGN');

fruits = [
   {"type" : "orange"},
   {"type" : "apple"},
   {"type" : "banana"}
];
newfruits = fruits.map(fruit => Object.assign({price: "$1.00"}, fruit));

log('fruits', JSON.stringify(fruits));
log('newfruits', JSON.stringify(newfruits));
log('^-- Only newfruits is modified since its a new array with new objects');
```

```css
pre {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this:

#### Side effects with the comma operator

If you want to do it inline you can use the comma operator (though it's a little obscure):

```
fruits.map((fruit) => (fruit.price = "$1.00", fruit))
```

We could also use `&&` since assignment returns the assigned value and `"$1.00"` is truthy but the comma operator is more general, since we can also set `false` or `0` and have everything continue to work.

#### Higher-ordered functions

It's probably better to make a helper function, however:

```
// We're currying manually here, but you could also make the signature
// setter(name, value) and use your function of choice to curry when you need to.
function setter(name) {
  return (value) => (obj) => {
    obj[name] = value;
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
fruits.map(setter("price")("$1.00"))
```

#### Embrace mutability

As [@Suppen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4146602/suppen) points out in their comment, because normal JavaScript objects are mutable you can also avoid the `map` and use `forEach` instead:

```
fruits.forEach(fruit => fruit.price = "$1.00");
// Each element in fruits has been modified in-place.
```

Comment: So why would anyone choose the first two solutions over `forEach`? They don't map anything after all.

Comment: @zeroflagL - because you actually want a copy of the `fruits` array, not the same array for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

A mapping function should almost always be pure. If you are only going to modify the objects, a simple loop will do better (`for (let fruit of fruits) fruit.price = …; console.log(fruits);`).

So when you're returning a new object, a one-liner will be easy:

```
console.log(fruits.map(({type}) => ({type, price:"$1.00"})));
```

If you've got many properties, or properties you don't know, then `Object.assign({}, …)` is your friend (as in @joews' comment to @RGraham's answer).